# Loading XAP based on Silverlight Version

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight application running across many different locations.  I want to upgrade to Silverlight 5 but unfortunately several of our large sites have antiquated IT departments that are dragging their feet on the upgrade.  They're telling me it's going to be at least 4-6 months before than can be running Silverlight 5.  What I'm wondering is this:  Can I build a Silverlight 4 version of my XAP and a Silverlight 5 version of my XAP and then load the correct version based on which version of the Silverlight client is running on the machine accessing my site.

Is this even possible?  I've searched around and I didn't see anything pointing me in the right direction so I came here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible to choose to load a different XAP depending on the version of the Silverlight plugin the user has.  The key is to use the [`Silverlight.isInstalled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838126(VS.95).aspx#isinstalled) JavaScript function.

You'll need to make a couple of small modifications to the HTML used to display your Silverlight application:

- add an ID such as `id="slObj"` to your Silverlight `<object ...>` element.
- remove the element `<param name="source" value="...">`.  The value of this parameter will be determined at runtime by JavaScript.

Once you've done that, you can call a function such as the following to load the correct Silverlight application.  I've assumed your Silverlight HTML `<object>` element has an `id` of `slObj`:

```
    function loadCorrectSilverlightXAP() {
        var slObj = document.getElementById("slObj");
        if (Silverlight.isInstalled("5.0.0.0")) {
            slObj.source = "URLOfMySilverlight5App.xap";
        } else {
            slObj.source = "URLOfMySilverlight4App.xap";
        }
    }
```